# How To Use Angular Service In Controller - TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to write angularjs with using typescript but i'm stuck right now. I have one service named AgeService. That service has a function named calculateAge. Im calling it into my controller but im getting an error written in below.

## SERVICE.TS

```
var servicesModule = angular.module('services', []);
class AgeService {
    static AngularDependency = [AgeService];
    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {

    }
    public calculateAge(birthdate: string) {
        var today = new Date();
        var dob = new Date(Date.parse(birthdate));

        var years = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
        if (today.getMonth() < dob.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() == dob.getMonth() && today.getDate() < dob.getDate()))
            years -= 1;
        return years;
    }
}

servicesModule.service('ageService', AgeService.AngularDependency)
```

## CONTROLLER.TS

```
var controllersModule = angular.module('controllers', []);
class PersonController {
    static AngularDependency = ['$scope', PersonController, 'ageService'];

    constructor(private $scope: PersonScope, private ageService: AgeService) {
        this.initController();
    }

    private initController() {
        this.$scope.name = 'Berkin';
        this.$scope.person = {
            name: 'Berkin',
            dob: '25-06-1995'
        };
        this.$scope.person.age = this.ageService.calculateAge(this.$scope.person.dob);
    }

}

controllersModule.controller('personController', PersonController.AngularDependency);
```

## HTML

```
<h4 ng-controller="personController">{{name}} {{person.age}}</h4>
```

ERROR

[image: Error]

Thanks...

Comment: Why you are using angular 1 in angular 2?

Comment: i guess he is not using angular 1 in angular 2; its angular 1 only but written in TS and he should be referencing to .js file eventually in his index.html

Comment: why `PersonController.AngularDependency`  only `PersonController` should work right?

Comment: i would suggest better to wrap the code inside typescript module

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION

Firstly, i wrap my codes into modules as @Rahul said.

After it, I omit "PersonController" variable into AngularDependency array.

Import the "Service" module into "Controller" module to create an istance of   AgeService.

Everything works fine now.

## CONTROLLER.TS

```
module Application.Controller {
import Services = Application.Services;

class PersonController {
        static AngularDependency = ['$scope', 'ageService'];
        ageService: Application.Services.AgeService;
        constructor(private $scope: PersonScope, ageService: Application.Services.AgeService) {          
            this.ageService = ageService;
            this.initController();
        }

        private initController() {
            this.$scope.name = 'Berkin';
            this.$scope.person = { name: 'Berkin', dob: '01-01-1995' };
            this.$scope.person.age = this.ageService.calculateAge(this.$scope.person.dob);
        }
    }
}
```

## SERVICES.TS

```
module Application.Services {
    var servicesModule = angular.module('services', []);

    export class AgeService {
        static AngularDependency = [AgeService];

        public calculateAge(birthdate: string) {
            var today = new Date();
            var dob = new Date(Date.parse(birthdate));
            var years = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
            if (today.getMonth() < dob.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() == dob.getMonth() && today.getDate() < dob.getDate()))
                years -= 1;
            return years;
        }
    }

    servicesModule.service('ageService', AgeService);
}
```

If these steps is not enough for you, please inform me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
App.filter('ageFilter', function() {
    //<input type="text" ng-model="employee.birthday | ageFilter" class="form-control" disabled/>
     function calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a 
         var birthday = new Date(birthday);
         var NOW = Date.now();
         var ageDifMs =  NOW - birthday.getTime();
         var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
         return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
     }
     function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
       if (d1 < d2){
        var months = d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth();
        return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
       }
       return 0;
     }

     return function(birthdate) { 
         if(angular.isUndefined(birthdate) || birthdate instanceof Date){ return ""; }else{

           return calculateAge(birthdate);
        }
     }; 
});
```